# Is it possible to enable directwrite in chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts, directwrite

I prefer google chrome in almost every way above IE10, but one thing I hate is that fonts just look much better in IE10. This especially visible with small math fonts. They look like pdf quality in IE10.

After searching a little bit, I found out that this is because IE10 use DirectWrite in windows 7/8 for font rendering. I was searching if chrome will support this in the future and I found this information:

[Apr 24, 2013](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137692#c104):

> An update for everyone that's watching this one:
>
> Our Windows font rendering is actively being worked on. Basic support
>   for DirectWrite is now in Skia (to update from comment #13). At the
>   same time, GDI was very deeply embedded in the Windows WebKit port and
>   is still being rooted out. We hope to have something within a
>   milestone or two that developers can start playing with. How fast it
>   goes to stable is, as always, all about how fast we can root out and
>   burn down any regressions.
>
> We'll update the thread here **when it's available behind a runtime flag
>   for y'all to try out.**

[Oct 8, 2013](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25541#c55)

> The following revision refers to this bug:
>       http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?view=rev&rev=159071
>   Changed paths:    M http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/core/platform/graphics/skia/FontCacheSkiaWin.cpp?r1=159071&r2=159070&pathrev=159071
>   M
>   http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/core/page/RuntimeEnabledFeatures.in?r1=159071&r2=159070&pathrev=159071
>   **Add runtime flag for using DirectWrite on windows**
>   Add runtime enabled feature for using the DirectWrite skia backend on
>   windows.
>   BUG=25541 R=bungeman@chromium.org, eseidel@chromium.org
>   Review URL: https://codereview.chromium.org/26335002

I don't even know what a runtime flag is, but this sounds to me that it may be possible to somehow enable directwrite in chrome. Is this true ? Or should I wait a little longer before I can use directwrite font rendering in chrome ?

Answer (score 8):

Sadly not yet (as of 2013-10-31, no Chromium channels supports this feature out-of-the-box).

If you look at the latest [RuntimeEnabledFeatures.in](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/platform/RuntimeEnabledFeatures.in), `DirectWrite` doesn't have any `status` assigned to it. According to [Blink document](http://www.chromium.org/blink/runtime-enabled-features), users cannot enable a feature via `about:flags` unless `status=experimental` is assigned.

But hopefully soon, so windows users may have a better time with web fonts :)

**Update 2013-11-16**: with [latest issue 25541 comment](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25541#c57), it seems we are very close to be able to enable DirectWrite in Canary.

**Update 2014-01-04**: Canary build now has a [command line switch](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25541#c61) that can enable DirectWrite font rendering, but disabling sandbox mode are required (not safe for everyday browsing). There are also a few font rendering problem associate with it. Hopefully they can get them fixed and add this feature to `about:flags` soon.

**Update 2014-05-09**: latest Canary build (m36) now has proper support for DirectWrite within sandbox mode (implemented via [issue 333029](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=333029)), which means developers can enable DW directly by going to `about:flags#enable-direct-write`. As for consumers, Google is targeting release on [m37](http://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar).

**Update 2014-08-09**: [Chrome 37 beta enables DirectWrite by default](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/07/chrome-37-beta-directwrite-on-windows.html), expect Chrome 37 official release to have it by default as well.

**Update 2014-08-31**: Chrome 37 stable release has [DirectWrite enabled by default](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2014/08/stable-channel-update_26.html)! Just note that users can still turn it off at `about:flags` (some of them use MacType instead).

Comment: Is there any way to keep it turned off? Just upgraded to Chrome v31 and issues are already starting to pop up about ClearType (DirectWrite): https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=319429 and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=320016

Comment: As far as I know, this is not in Canary yet, so very unlikely issues in Stable channel is related to DirectWrite.

Comment: @bitinn Does this mean it is now in Canary ? http://www.chromestatus.com/features/4725550652325888

Comment: @90intuition not yet, this just means they are in active development. click the star next to title on this page and you will receive email when there are official updates: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25541

Comment: @bitinn Did you see the latest comit ?

Comment: Is it possible to enable DirectWrite from the code? I would really like to force older versions of Chrome to use DirectWrite on my sites. I've had bit issues with my clients over font rendering problem in Chrome and Opera.

Comment: @DanielDogeanu nope, text rendering is a user choice, not a developer choice, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome 35 (beta) comes with an option to enable DirectWrite for Windows font rendering. Paste the following command in your address bar and click enable:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-direct-write
```

Reference: http://www.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/22q9r9/chrome_35_beta_has_finally_fixed_windows_font/

Answer (score 2):

It's currently in development for chrome on windows.
http://www.chromestatus.com/features/4725550652325888

Answer (score 1):

Update: on August 26, 2014, Google updated the stable version of their Chrome browser to version 37.0.2062.94 on Windows, OS X, and Linux. With this release, Chrome move from Microsoft's Graphics Device Interface rendering method to Microsoft's DirectWrite text rendering API. Switching to DirectWrite has been requested for years by users on Windows, and Google has stated that it took significant rewriting of their font rendering engine which is why it has taken so long.

Answer (score 0):

It's in Chrome as a flag as of 33 (and as of this time of writing), however from what I understand you still need to run it with the sandbox disabled via the command line `--no-sandbox`. This is *not* a recommended action for everyday use. You can enable the rendering flag, but it will only change if sandboxing is disabled.

*(I would have added this as a comment to @chickenbooze, but I've switched SE accounts and don't have enough reputation yet :)*